# How can I pass an implementation of "IStorageItem" to DataPackage.SetStorageItems(items) and don't get an InvalidCastException raised on UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm developing a UWP application which shall be able to share its files. I followed [the documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/share-data) and the solution worked pretty well.

Here is my implementation:

```
public void ShareLocalFile(LocalFileToShare file)
{
    DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested += async (sender, args) =>
    {
        var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();

        try
        {
            var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(file.FilePath).AsTask();

            args.Request.Data.SetStorageItems(new[] { storageFile });
        }
        finally
        {
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    };

    DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
}
```

However, the app stores all files with not human-readable names which makes users be uneasy with the sharing.
So, I wanted to share a file with an alternative name without actually renaming it on the file system because files are opened in a third-party reader. In addition, the files are quite big and copying them with new names is not a good choice.

Firstly I thought that I could make a symbolic link but [it's only possible with Administrator rights](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/why-do-you-have-to-be-an-admin-to-create-a-symlink-in-windows)

Then I looked at [the signature of "void DataPackage.SetStorageItems(IEnumerable value)" method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.setstorageitems) and guessed that it's probably possible to pass there my own implementation of [IStorageItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.istorageitem) what I did:

```
public class StorageItemWithAlternativeName : IStorageItem
{
    private readonly IStorageItem storageItem;

    public StorageItemWithAlternativeName(IStorageItem storageItem, string alternativeItemName)
    {
        this.storageItem = storageItem;
        Name = alternativeItemName;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    // the interface implementation omitted for briefness but it simply delegates all actions to the decorated storageItem
}

public static class LocalFileToShareExtensions
{
    public static async Task<IStorageItem> GetStorageItem(this LocalFileToShare file)
    {
        var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(file.FilePath).AsTask();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file.AlternativeFileName))
        {
            storageFile = new StorageItemWithAlternativeName(storageFile, file.AlternativeFileName);
        }

        return storageFile;
    }
}
```

And here I failed. The error is quite silly - SetStorageItems method throws an InvalidCastException:
*"No such interface supported.
The collection contains item(s) that can't be converted to read-only form."*

I investigated the windows event log and found the following entry:

```
Faulting application name: [MyApp].Windows.exe, version: 7.0.0.0, time stamp:    0x5bb69bfe
Faulting module name: combase.dll, version: 10.0.17763.253, time stamp: 0xa3f81b2d
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x00209931
Faulting process id: 0x4ee4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4be3ccca1f00f
Faulting application path: [PathToMyApp].Windows.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
Report Id: 35999df1-6b4f-4675-a821-a84e6ea0cfb4
Faulting package full name: [MyAppPackageName]
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

It seems that the DataPackage object communicates with COM so I also tried `[assembly: [ComVisible(true)]` attribute on my assembly but I did not succeed.

The question is **how can I kind of dumb the system and share a file with a different name?** Is it possible to pass my own implementations to UWP SDK methods? Because now it violates [the Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

I will appreciate any help with this!

Comment: IStorageItem exists so that both StorageFolder and StorageFile can implement it. But you are not allowed to implement it in your custom classes. What you want is StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileAsync. This lets you create virtual files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use the overloaded method `SetStorageItems` with parameter `readOnly:false`, something like this:

```
args.Request.Data.SetStorageItems(new[] { storageFile }, false);
```

Comment: Thank you, @Alexander!


It worked with a little trick. I also had to implement all interfaces from `StorageFile`:


`class StorageFileWithAlternativeName : IStorageFile, IStorageItemProperties2, IStorageItem2, IStorageItemPropertiesWithProvider, IStorageFilePropertiesWithAvailability, IStorageFile2`


I guess some of them are unnecessary but if only `IStorageItem` interface is implemented then a file cannot be attached to an email in MailClient.


**P.S.** _Skype_ crashes with this approach although I am ok with this since I only need MailClient working properly.

Comment: Cool, @GennadiySakhnyuk,!